# How To Specify Particular Master Page For Mobile Devices - SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I am working in SharePoint 2013 Foundation, and I need to apply some CSS styles to mobile view. I have already created the additional master page for that purpose but unable to find a setting where I can tell SharePoint to use this particular master page only in mobile view. I found similar settings information on Microsoft home page however they apply only to SP Server and Office 365.

Could you please suggest how can I specify a particular master page on SharePoint 2013 Foundation or in case the option does not exist any other suggestion to apply mobile styles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862343.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> Device channels are available only for SharePoint 2013 publishing
> sites.
>
> You can create and configure a device channel from the Site Settings
> menu under the Look and Feel section, or alternatively through the
> Design Manager option in the same section. When you create a device
> channel item, there are five required and optional fields to supply
> for the process.
>
> After a device channel is created and activated, device redirection to
> a specific master page, for example a mobile version, is possible. The
> next step is to specify what master page should be displayed for
> mobile devices at the site level, through either the Site Master Page
> Settings or by using the Publish and Apply option in Design Manager.

Since you use foundation, you can [deactivate the mobile view](http://academy.bindtuning.com/deactivate-sharepoint-2013-mobile-view/) and use media queries/responsive design.

Alternatively, you can try to [change the master page dynamically](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43377/SharePoint-Dynamically-Change-Master-Page.aspx).

Comment: I have already read the article before asking. There is no such options in Foundation.. The thing written here apply to SharePoint 2013 Server Edition and Office 365

Comment: yeah, I had a feeling you'd say that. don't think there is an ootb way to do it with foundation. perhaps with some custom code, but perhaps you'd be better off disabling the mobile view and then use media queries

Comment: updated answer!

Comment: Yeah, already did so, thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score -1):

So whats the deal here... Go to Master Page in Site Settings and select your master page. If your custom master page is not appearing there then you have not published it.

Comment: I see the master page there but cant find option to enable it only for mobile device

Comment: Oh you want it only for Mobile device..In that case you need to use Device Channel or you got to write your media queries in the master page according to the size of the device.

Comment: Yeah, its closer to the topic :) I know how to style my master page to have responsive design, but how I can apply styles to different file specified master page?

Comment: IF you written the code correctly and have published it...you should be seeing the changes on changing the size of the window. IF still you are facing issue, there can be other reason...Check from SharePoint Designer if you have set your master page as both Default and Custom Master page. You will get this option on right click of your master page.

Comment: And if you are wondering about device channel, enable the Publishing feature of the site.

Comment: I did not write any code yet, I just created a new master page in SP Designer, and can't select it as default one, as only one default file should be selected. In SP 2013 SERVER one there is option in Design Manager to specify the file for mobile view. There is no, or I cannot find, such option in Foundation

Comment: Thats a part of Publishing Feature. You have SharePoint Foundation..Its not available there

Comment: Yeah, I already started to understand this :) So the question is not relevant then... Just thought maybe there are some other options. Anyway thanks for answers.